# InputHidden not working with actionFunction

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller, wrapper-class

I'm trying to pass the value of an html input tag to an wrapper class into my controller. I'm using input tag because I need the slds style and others validation that I can't with a simple apex:inputField.

If I use the apex:inputHidden with the html input tag, the save method is not being called on my Controller but if I just use the apex:inputField works like a charm.

Did anyone knows if there is an error with the structure?

```
<apex:pageBlock mode="maindetail">
<apex:form id="theForm">
<apex:actionFunction name="saveinfo" action="{!save}" oncomplete="return false;"/>
        <apex:pageblocktable value="{!wrapperMainPaxList}" var="wrapper" columnsWidth="5%,5%,80%,10%" width="500px" headerclass="headercolor" >
            <apex:column>
                <apex:inputHidden value="{!wrapper.qlis.Date__c}" id="hiddencmp"/>
                <input type="date" id="input-id-01" class="slds-input" aria-describedby="form-error-01" placeholder="Date" onblur="document.getElementById('{!$Component.hiddencmp}').value = this.value;" value=""/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!wrapper.qlis.Date__c}"/>
            </apex:column>
        </apex:pageblocktable>
</apex:form>
</apex:pageBlock>
<button class="slds-button slds-button_brand" onclick="saveInformation();">Submit</button>
```

Comment: Where you have declared `saveInformation()`

Comment: Hello Tushar, I have between script tags `function saveInformation(){
                saveinfo();
        }
`

Comment: Add `apex:pagereference` tag in your page. You might be getting some exception.

Comment: I just added and didn't showed anything, on the debug logs, it get generate, but it is a file that does not show anything useful... any other idea about how can I debug that?

Comment: Is the save method not getting called or the value in `inputHidden` is not getting passed to controller?Also, it seems the script you have written for onblur is not pointing to the correct element `id` `document.getElementById('{!$Component.hiddencmp}').value = this.value;` All the `ids` in the hierarchy are not given. Try inspecting the hidden element and check its `id`

Comment: Hello Hemant, when I use apex:inputfield the save method is being called (it has only a system.debug inside for now) but if I change to the input tag with inputHidden, the save is not being called, I looked into the logs and is not even passing there.. how can I see the hidden element as you said?

Comment: I suppose the onblur function is giving error and so subsquent script is not getting executed. Right click in the browser and select inspect element(if you are using chrome). Check console tab and look for any errors after save in it. For debugging, checkout this [link](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/inspect-styles/)

Comment: thank you Guys, I may have found the problem but not an solution. The field that I'm trying to show it's from the wrapper class and the custom object inside this wrapper (Date type). So I put an log inside these fields and the "wrapper.qlis.Date__c" it's returning "Sat Jun 30 00:00:00 GMT 2018" and the input html tag is returning "2018-06-08". Probably because they are different "types" it's failing, what would be the best approach?

Comment: Hey, thank you all! I found an solution. I just added this fields that I need to convert on my wrapper class.